# Logstash conditional not matching

Tags: logstash-grok, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

Im trying to match a substring in my conditional filter, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have a log like this:

```
<30>ddns[21535]: Dynamic DNS update for xxx (Duck DNS) successful
```

And I am trying to match the `ddns` part of the log, since logs can also be sent by different services.

Currently my filter looks like this:
filter {

```
if [program] =~ "ddns" {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "<%{PROG:syslog_pri}>%{DATA:program}[%{INT:pid}]: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
        add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
    }
}
    syslog_pri { }

    date {
        match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "yyyy:MM:dd-HH:mm:ss" ]
    }

    mutate {
        replace => [ "@source_host", "sflne01.sarandasnet.local" ]
        replace => [ "@message", "%{syslog_message}" ]
        remove_field  => [ "syslog_message", "syslog_timestamp" ]
    }
}
```

I have also tried using `if [program] =~ /^ddns$/`, but without success.

UPDATED CONFIG:

```
filter {
################
# START IPFIRE #
################
if [host] =~ /172\.16\.0\.1/ {
    if [program] =~ /(?:k|kernel)/ {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "<%{PROG:syslog_pri}>%{DATA:program}: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
            add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
        }
    }

    if [prog] =~ /^ddns$/ {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "<%{PROG:syslog_pri}>%{DATA:program}\[%{INT:pid}\]: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
            add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
        }
    }

    syslog_pri { }

    date {
        match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "yyyy:MM:dd-HH:mm:ss" ]
    }

    mutate {
        replace => [ "@source_host", "sflne01.sarandasnet.local" ]
        replace => [ "@message", "%{syslog_message}" ]
        remove_field  => [ "syslog_message", "syslog_timestamp" ]
    }

    kv {
        source => "@message"
    }

    geoip {
        source => "SRC"
        target => "geoip"
        database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
    }

    mutate {
        convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
    }
}
################
#  END IPFIRE  #
################
}
```

Comment: What's in your field program? Did you create that field with the value of your log? If not, then the field does not exist and the conditional will always be false.

Comment: Also, it's not in your question, but your grok filter has a problem, the `[` and `]`must be escaped with \ like this : `\[` and `\]`

Comment: @baudsp I have added the full config. I am just concerned about the ddns part, the rest works.

Comment: Thank you. What value is supposed to be `prog`?

Answer (score 1):

I made the conditional work using this:

```
if [message] =~ /ddns/
```

I think you have to use `/` instead of `"` so that `ddns` is used as a regex.

There is an error with `/^ddns$/`: The `^` anchors at the start of the string and `$` at the end. So the only thing this regex will match is `ddns`. You'll have to remove both if you want the regex to match `ddns` anywhere in the string

Comment: It's not matching for me. I get the following output:
`{`
       `"message" => "<30>ddns[21535]: Dynamic DNS update for xxx`
`(Duck DNS) successful",`
      `"@version" => "1",`
    `"@timestamp" => "2016-08-19T11:15:19.419Z",`
          `"host" => "sflsv006.sarandasnet.local"`
`}`
It is also not creating the fields, such as `program` or `pid`.

Comment: @ou_snaaksie which field are you comparing with `/ddns/`? If it's `prog`, how is it initialized? And which value is it supposed to have?